# Expect multiple not_to change expectations in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to make sure certain data has remain unchanged by a single action:

```
expect {
  # running migration and user reload here
}.not_to change(user, :avatar_url).from(sample_avatar_url).and change(user, :old_avatar).from(nil)
```

`sample_avatar_url` is a string defined in the beginning of the spec file.

Basically, I want to check whether the `avatar_url` and `old_avatar` remain untouched by what's happening in the `expect` block.

The output from the above code is:

> `expect(...).not_to matcher.and matcher` is not supported, since it creates a bit of an ambiguity. Instead, define negated versions of whatever matchers you wish to negate with `RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher` and use `expect(...).to matcher.and matcher`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This doesn't work because it's not clear reading whether thats supposed to mean not change the first and not change the second, or not change the first but change the second.  You have a couple of options to get around this

Since you're checking static values just don't use change

```
..run migration and user reload..
expect(user.avatar_url).to eq(sample_avatar_url)
expect(user.old_avatar).to eq nil
```

or use define_negated_matcher to create a not_change matcher

```
RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :not_change, :change
expect {
  # running migration and user reload here
}.to not_change(user, :avatar_url).from(sample_avatar_url).and not_change(user, :old_avatar).from(nil)
```

Comment: Simplifying it with the first example does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome - just note that does check slightly less since it's only checking that a specific value is set, not that it hasn't been changed from something else to that value - If thats enough of test for your use case great.

Comment: Placing `RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher(:not_change, :change)`  in rails_helper.rb gave my RSpec superpowers.

Answer (score 1):

i know it is long ago but i had a similar problem and did something like this:

```
expect {
  # running migration and user reload here
}.not_to change { user.slice(:avatar_url, :old_avatar) }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Thomas answer, it does not work because it's not clear reading and you can create a negated matcher. Another option is to use the [saharspec gem](https://github.com/zverok/saharspec) and its [`dont`](https://github.com/zverok/saharspec#dont-matcher-negation) matcher negation.

Here is an extract from the project's README:

> Another (experimental) attempt to get rid of `define_negated_matcher`. `dont` is not 100% grammatically correct, yet short and readable enought. It just negates attached matcher.
>
> ```
> # before
> RSpec.define_negated_matcher :not_change, :change
>
> it { expect { code }.to do_stuff.and not_change(obj, :attr) }
>
> # after: no `define_negated_matcher` needed
> require 'saharspec/matchers/dont'
>
> it { expect { code }.to do_stuff.and dont.change(obj, :attr) }
> ```

So you can write your expectation without creating a negated matcher like this:

```
expect {
  # running migration and user reload here
}.to dont.change(user, :avatar_url).from(sample_avatar_url).and 
    dont.change(user, :old_avatar).from(nil)
```